# How to test a void method in JUnit

Tags: java, testing, junit, junit5

Since it is mandatory that I have to write test in my company, we have to write Unit Tests for every method that can be tested.
My problem now is that I have a method which has the return value
**void** here is how the method looks currently:

```
public void saveCarDriver(CarDriverDto carDriver) {
    BOCarDriver bo = CarDriver.findByCarDrivernoI(carDriver.getId());
    if (bo == null) {
        bo = new BOCarDriver();
    }
    CarDriverDtoMapper.copyToBo(bo, carDriver);
    save(bo);
}
```

This is the method itself, now here is the JUnit test what I tried so far but of course didn't work:

```
@Test
public void saveCarDriverShouldFindOneCarDriverIfOneWasCreatedBeforeTheMethod() {
    Transaction trans = new Transaction();
    DDCarDriverRow carDriverRow = new DDCarDriverRow();
    carDriverRow.setCarDrivernoi(1);
    DARow.saveToTransaction(carDriverRow, trans);
    trans.execute();
    
    CarDriverDto dto = new CarDriverDto();
    dto.setId(1);
    assertEquals(1, this.testy.saveCarDriver(dto).getSize());
}
```

Comment: Here you need to test the **change that the method brings in into the system**, in this case the database table. You can do that only by going to the database and fetching the record(s) and checking!

Comment: In addition to what's said in the previous comment, you can test the behaviour of the method when called with `null` and other invalid arguments.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to fetch from db to test. If your repositories are mocked in the test, you can verify the interactions with the appropriate methods - execute `saveCarDriver()` in the test and then verify number of interactions with `repository.save()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't look as if it is designed for testability. While you always could try with an integration test (her: execute the code with a real connection to the database and look if it has the expected impact there), this doesn't allow for a very isolated test of just that method.

Please note that you have to differentiate between "JUnit test" and "unit test". The first is a framework to implement assertions of test results and also execute the tests, but it doesn't enforce "unit tests".

A "unit test" is a test that tests a publicly accessible unit of source code and only that unit, without any actual calls to other units. As "publicly accessible" in Java I consider every method that doesn't have `private` visibility.

To isolate your unit of code (in your case it's the method `public void saveCarDriver(CarDriverDto carDriver)`) for the test you have to "mock" everything outside, best in a way that you can verify all calls to that outside stuff and control what it's return values are.

A widely used framework for this it [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/). There are other frameworks for that, but I'm only familiar with this one.

For mocking, your code has the problem that it relies on many `static` methods, like `CarDriver.findByCarDrivernoI` and `CarDriverDtoMapper.copyToBo`. This makes it unneccessarily hard to replace the implementations of these two methods with mocked code - it is possible but if there is any chance for you to change these to non-`static` methods I would go for it - it will increase testability of all code that uses them.

Usually you `inject` the instances that provide those methods to the class that contains the methods. This means you provide them as constructor parameter and store them as member fields. Dependency injection frameworks like Spring or Google Guice help with annotations so that you don't have to provide all that by hand.

In the test you provide mocks instead of the real classes, then in your test you can

- verify that the external methods were called with the expected parameters.
- control that all code paths in your tested method are executed.

For your method this would mean that you have two tests:

1. let `findByCarDrivernoI` return a regular instance and check that this instance is then passed to the `copyToBo` method.
2. let `findByCarDrivernoI` return `null` and check that still a call to `copyToBo` is done.

As the `save` method is a method of your own class, it's delicate to test. If it's `private` you have to include all it's actions into your regular tests as if it was direct part of your method. You cannot test `private` methods or interactions with them separately. Otherwise (if it's not `public` you could create a spy of the class to test and stub only the `save` method, but leave the rest of the code under test untouched. Then you can verify the call to `save`.

I can't give a full introduction into unit testing and testability and dependency injection in this one answer, but you should have a coarse overview.

And all of the described techniques are state of the art (aka *neither* "cutting edge" nor "bleeding edge" technologies), so your colleagues should already know about them, use them and be able to help you a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You could test if the method throws an exception or not. Your method saves an entity to the database, so something "can" fail during the save.

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

@Test
public void shouldNotFail() {
    Assertions.assertDoesNotThrow(() -> {
            // your method saveCarDriver() here
    });
}
```

IMO I wouldn't recommend going down this route, maybe think about what you want to achieve and re-write the method just so that it does return something that you can test against.

Answer (score 0):

Does `save(...)` return anything? Maybe it would be worth returning a boolean from `save(...)` to determine if the call was successful or not, subsequently returning that value from `saveCarDriver(...)` and running an assert on that in your test code.

Example code:

```
public boolean saveCarDriver(CarDriverDto carDriver) {
    BOCarDriver bo = CarDriver.findByCarDrivernoI(carDriver.getId());
    if (bo == null) {
        bo = new BOCarDriver();
    }
    CarDriverDtoMapper.copyToBo(bo, carDriver);
    return save(bo); 
}
```

Test Code:

```
@Test
public void saveCarDriverShouldFindOneCarDriverIfOneWasCreatedBeforeTheMethod() {
    Transaction trans = new Transaction();
    DDCarDriverRow carDriverRow = new DDCarDriverRow();
    carDriverRow.setCarDrivernoi(1);
    DARow.saveToTransaction(carDriverRow, trans);
    trans.execute();

    CarDriverDto dto = new CarDriverDto();
    dto.setId(1);
    assertTrue(this.testy.saveCarDriver(dto));
}
```